# error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'PlDrustvo' and 'PlDrustvo')|

Tags: c++

I was coding for university and i stuck in one assignment.It says ,
"error : not match for 'operator'=", but i have overloaded the '=' so i couldn't find the problem.Can someone help me out?
Thanks

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class PlDrustvo{
private:
    char *ime;
    int turi;
    int brclenovi;
public:
    PlDrustvo(){  ime = new char[1];
        strcpy(ime, " ");
        turi = 0;
        brclenovi = 0;}
    PlDrustvo(char *ime, int turi, int brclenovi){
    this->ime=new char[strlen(ime)+1];
    strcpy(this->ime,ime);
    this->turi=turi;
    this->brclenovi=brclenovi;
    }
    PlDrustvo(PlDrustvo &p){
    this->ime=new char[strlen(p.ime)+1];
    strcpy(this->ime,p.ime);
    this->turi=p.turi;
    this->brclenovi=p.brclenovi;
    }
    PlDrustvo operator+(PlDrustvo &c){
    PlDrustvo temp;
    temp.brclenovi=this->brclenovi+ c.brclenovi;
    if(this->brclenovi>c.brclenovi){
        temp.ime=new char[strlen(this->ime)+1];
        strcpy(temp.ime,this->ime);
        temp.turi=this->turi;
        }
    else
    {
     temp.ime=new char[strlen(c.ime)+1];
     strcpy(temp.ime,c.ime);
     temp.turi=c.turi;
    }
    return temp;
    }
    PlDrustvo& operator=(PlDrustvo &p){
    if(this!=&p)
    {
        delete [] this->ime;
        this->ime=new char[strlen(p.ime)+1];
    strcpy(this->ime,p.ime);
    this->turi=p.turi;
    this->brclenovi=p.brclenovi;
    }
    return *this;

    }
bool operator>(PlDrustvo &p){
return this->brclenovi>p.brclenovi;
}
bool operator<(PlDrustvo &p){
return brclenovi<p.brclenovi;
}
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &alek, PlDrustvo &p){
alek<<"Ime: "<<p.ime<<" Turi: "<<p.turi<<" Clenovi: "<<p.brclenovi<<endl;
return alek;
}
friend void najmnoguClenovi(PlDrustvo*, int);
};
void najmnoguClenovi(PlDrustvo *pl,int n){
int i_max = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        if(pl[i].brclenovi > pl[i_max].brclenovi)
            i_max = i;
    cout << "Najmnogu clenovi ima planinarskoto drustvo: " << pl[i_max];
}
int main()
{
    PlDrustvo drustva[3];
    PlDrustvo pl;
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        char ime[100];
        int brTuri;
        int brClenovi;
        cin>>ime;
        cin>>brTuri;
        cin>>brClenovi;
        PlDrustvo p(ime,brTuri,brClenovi);
        drustva[i] = p;

    }

    pl = drustva[0] + drustva[1]; //HERE IS THE ERROR
    cout<<pl;

    najmnoguClenovi(drustva, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: Always program in English. And indent better.

Comment: Use std::string! You can't strcpy "  " into an array of size 1!

Comment: _i couldn't find the problem_ that's because there are 100 lines of code there. Reduce it to a [mcve] and you might see the problem (as well as aid others helping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PlDrustvo& operator=(PlDrustvo &p){
```

Should be

```
PlDrustvo& operator=(PlDrustvo const &p){
```

The exact error message is:

> error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'PlDrustvo&' to an rvalue of type 'PlDrustvo'

The return value of the summation operation is a temporary of type `PlDrustvo`, and temporaries cannot bind to non-const references, so the compiler cannot pass the result of the summation expression to your copy-assignment operator.  The solution is to make `operator=` accept a const reference instead, which makes more sense anyway since it doesn't modify the argument.

With that change, [your code compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81e658f5edd73e91).

---

In general, your program suffers from a lack of const-correctness.  Here are all of the other const issues I found:

```
/* bad  */ PlDrustvo(char *ime, int turi, int brclenovi){
/* good */ PlDrustvo(char const *ime, int turi, int brclenovi){

/* bad  */ PlDrustvo(PlDrustvo &p){
/* good */ PlDrustvo(PlDrustvo const &p){

/* bad  */ PlDrustvo operator+(PlDrustvo &c) {
/* good */ PlDrustvo operator+(PlDrustvo const &c) const {

/* bad  */ bool operator>(PlDrustvo &p){
/* good */ bool operator>(PlDrustvo const &p){

/* bad  */ bool operator<(PlDrustvo &p){
/* good */ bool operator<(PlDrustvo const &p){

/* bad  */ friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &alek, PlDrustvo &p){
/* good */ friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &alek, PlDrustvo const &p){

/* bad  */ friend void najmnoguClenovi(PlDrustvo*, int);
/* good */ friend void najmnoguClenovi(PlDrustvo const*, int);

/* bad  */ void najmnoguClenovi(PlDrustvo *pl,int n){
/* good */ void najmnoguClenovi(PlDrustvo const *pl,int n){
```